# Jeninks CI: How to run integration test

Tags: postgresql, docker, jenkins

I am working on a project which uses postgres as backend. Jenkins is used for ci. So far only unit tests were included as part of the daily build, but now we want to include integration tests as well. This requires an api to access a database. The database is Postgres,liquibase is used as a publisher.
What I want to do is via Jenkins
1. Create database,
2. Publish it using liquibase
3. Run Integration tests

I created this docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  xyz.api:
    image: xyz.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ci
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - publisher
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xyz"
      POSTGRES_DB: "xyz_db"    
  publisher:
    image: publish
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-publish.ci
    entrypoint: ""
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5433"]
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:10.2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xyz"
      POSTGRES_DB: "xyz_db"
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5433
        protocol: tcp


networks:
  xyzapi:
```

dockerfile-publish

```
FROM sequenceiq/liquibase:latest
WORKDIR /workspace

    # copy project and restore as distinct layers
    RUN liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=/usr/local/bin/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar --changeLogFile=xyz_ChangeLog.xml --url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5433/xyz_db --username=postgres --password=xyz update
```

docker-compose up throws

```
 ---> Running in 18c564dac2de
Unexpected error running Liquibase: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

After trying a number of options including docker-compose I still could not get it working. I don't think I am on right track here and am asking for hint or direction on how to run integration tests in Jenkins for a project that depends on a database.

Comment: `./wait-for-it.sh, db:5433` should be `./wait-for-it.sh, postgresql:5433` no ?

Comment: And also one more thing, how do you want to connect to db container when you build the publish image? `RUN` command is executed when image is being build. Try using `CMD ["liquibase", "--driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=/usr/local/bin/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar",  "--changeLogFile=xyz_ChangeLog.xml", "--url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5433/xyz_db", "--username=postgres", "--password=xyz update"] `

Comment: Thanks, @michalk , sorry for being late to acknowledge your response. This helped me to move on and finish it up.